# Powershell: how to ensure endianess when storing int value

Tags: powershell, endianness

The task is how to store the bytes of an int value with the correct endianess.

Basically, this works fine when on x86 systems, and the value shall be little-endian, using the .NET function [GetBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-7.0#system-bitconverter-getbytes(system-int32)):

```
[byte[]]$as_little_endian = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($value)

# e.g.:
$value = 0x12345678
[byte[]]$as_little_endian = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($value)
$as_little_endian | Format-Hex

# -> ...    78 56 34 12
```

For example, the result can now be appended to a file when `$value` is a checksum.

However, the result depends on the system architecture and may be different on other systems. There is no way to *enforce* a certain endianess, to keep the script independent.

As a workaround, I do this:

```
$as_little_endian = [System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($value)

if( -Not [System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian )
{
    [array]::Reverse($as_little_endian )
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to enforce endianess here?

Comment: More recent .NET framework has [`BinaryPrimitives.Write…LittleEndian`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives.writeint32littleendian?view=net-7.0) family of functions, but they can't be used directly in PowerShell, because PS doesn't support `Span`.

Comment: What does getbytes do on a bigendian system?

Comment: @js2010 big-endian bytes, probably, according to the spec. My first thought was "one day the script runs on a Mac", turns out, Apple silicon uses little-endian for data as well. Nevertheless, it should always be architecture independent, as principle.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like getbytes() returns the right order automatically.  Note that tcp always uses bigendian.  It seems unlikely that you would encounter a bigendian system.

> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method
> depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or
> big-endian.

[BitConverter.GetBytes Method (System-int64) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-8.0#system-bitconverter-getbytes(system-int64))

Comment: The "right" order is defined by the *target* I want to produce the bytes for. In the concrete case, the bytes decorate a binary file for a microcontroller with a CRC. And I usually want my programs bullet-proof. I have seen code that did not and - bang - failed when executed on a different platform. That's what annoys me with Microsoft's approach "... depends on wheter the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian". It just should not to. Or should at least be definable. My yardstick for "defensive programming" ;-)

Comment: The `[System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian` test is irrelevant then.

Comment: It's not. On a big-endian system, the result must still be little-endian so bytes need to be reversed first. I used to develop software for a PowerPC Linux system, but debugging and testing on an x86. So it was crucial that the code generated the same result no matter where it ran. Usually by masking, bit shifting and ORing values together. Once someone contributed code that directly read from the memory... Wrong. That's why I am pedantic about endianness.